# Display keys of a dictionary after user input?

Tags: c#

Title's vague, but I hope my code and problem will help. In essence, I wish for a key of my dictionary *questionDict* to be  displayed, and if a certain user input is given (in this case, 'yes') then I want it to display the next key. I can understand where the problem is, just I can't resolve it. Apologies in advance if I sound amateur, but that's because I am.

```
namespace ELIZA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = //creating dictionary for questions and animals
                new Dictionary<string, string>();
            questionDict.Add("Does it have whiskers?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it purr?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it bark?", "dog");
            foreach (string test in questionDict.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("AW NAW");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The problem is (console transcript)

> Does it have whiskers?
>
> Yes
>
> Does it have whiskers?
>
> Yes
>
> Does it purr?
>
> Yes
>
> Does it purr?
>
> Yes
>
> *etc*

Comment: its good that you understand the source of the problem. now, mind sharing it with us too please?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is or what exactly you are asking..

Comment: Yes, I realised after posting. It's in the edit. Pretty much the problem is the program displaying the keys twice before moving on, if that makes sense.

Comment: You're writing the output twice, so you'll see the output twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider switching over to using [`KeyValuePair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of just using `string`.

```
namespace ELIZA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = //creating dictionary for questions and animals
                new Dictionary<string, string>();
            List<string> removeKeys = new List<string>();
            questionDict.Add("Does it have whiskers?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it purr?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it bark?", "dog");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in questionDict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", kvp.Key);
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", kvp.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    removeKeys.Add(kvp.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach(string rKey in removeKeys)
            {
                questionDict.Remove(rKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dave I edited my answer to fit your logic of `IF(userInput = "yes") THEN ask next question ELSE stop loop`

Comment: Ah, now, in the break; area, is there a way to make it not break the loop but instead remove the key from the dictionary? For instance, if the user were to answer 'no' to 'Does it bark?' is there a way to remove that question and its value from the dictionary?

Comment: @dave I'd have a variable outside the `for` loop to handle that because you cannot change a collection when iterating through it, but instead of `break;` use it to add the key to be removed. Updated as shown.

Comment: @dave Don't forget to click the `Checkmark` to indicate that this answer solves your question.

Answer (score 3):

In your `if` block, you display `test` again. Thus your output would be:

```
> Does it have whiskers?
> yes
> Does it have whiskers?
```

If you wanted "cat" as the output, you need to *index into* the dictionary:

```
if (userInput == "yes")
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", questionDict[test]); //Go get the value!
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which would result in:

```
> Does it have whiskers?
> yes
> cat
```

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful for my further intentions. However, what I need for it to do is ask all these questions first, so I can later use certain values to make a decision.

Comment: @dave Thats a bit more complex. You would need to store the users responses in a `List<String>` or `List<bool>` and iterate over them later. You'll need to rephrase or be more specific though, because I'm not sure how to help you accomplish that.

Comment: You wouldn't even need to store their responses, just store the keys of the ones they confirmed. Or if saying no will make an impact on the answer, store a `Dictionary<String, bool>` of the keys and answers.

Comment: @Pluto That approach would work as well, if not better

Answer (score 1):

I am still not really sure what you are trying to do, but your question states you are getting duplicate print outs before continuing. So to answer your question specifically (but I suspect you are asking more...)

Your Code:

```
foreach (string test in questionDict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userInput == "yes")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AW NAW");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see, your print the key, ask for input, then print the key again and ask for the input a second time. You should instead have:

```
foreach (string test in questionDict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userInput == "yes")
    {
        // do what you want, store the response, etc
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AW NAW");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
namespace ELIZA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = //creating dictionary for questions and animals
                new Dictionary<string, string>();
            questionDict.Add("Does it have whiskers?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it purr?", "cat");
            questionDict.Add("Does it bark?", "dog");
            String lastAnswer="";
            bool isFirstQuestion=true;

            foreach (string test in questionDict.Keys)
            {
                if(isFirstQuestion)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    isFirstQuestion=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lastAnswer == "yes")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("AW NAW");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                lastAnswer = Console.ReadLine();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This in no way solves the actual problem. Evidence: you still have `Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);` in the "yes" response block